# Cannot instal HTML Help 1.3 in WindowsXP

Tags: windows-xp, html-help

My system is running on Windows XP. I downloaded Microsoft HTML Help Control.exe. When Double clicked error message shown is "HTML Help 1.3 cannot be installed on Windows 2000".

Comment: How is this programming-related?

Comment: I am working with a VB6 Project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the HTML Help Workshop instead: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=00535334-c8a6-452f-9aa0-d597d16580cc&displaylang=en